# Borrar datos de un formulario y evitar que se envié con un boton

Tags: javascript, html, botón

Al intentar dar un valor al `<input>` desde una función me hace un amago pero no mantiene el valor. Quiero decir, durante una centésima de segundo se ve que pone el valor pero desaparece.

¿Sabéis por qué?

Muchas gracias a todos.

```html
<form action="" name="formulario" id="formulario">
  <input type="text" id="texto1" name="texto1" value="" placeholder="nombre">
  <input type="text" id="texto2" value="" placeholder="apellido">
  <input type="text" id="texto3" value="" placeholder="edad">
  <button id="boton1">Enviar</button>
  <button id="boton2">Eliminar</button>
</form>
<script>
  function datos() {
    var uno = document.getElementById("texto1").value;
    var dos = document.getElementById("texto2").value;
    var tres = document.getElementById("texto3").value;
    var arreglo = [uno, dos, tres];
    return arreglo;
  }

  function borrar() {
    document.getElementById("texto1").value = "rrrrr";
    document.getElementById("texto2").value = "rrrrr";
    document.getElementById("texto3").value = "rrrrr";
  }

  function alerta() {
    var arreglo = datos();
    alert(`Su nombre es ${arreglo[0]}, su apellido ${arreglo[1]} y su edad ${arreglo[2]}`);
  }
  boton1.onclick = alerta;
  boton2.onclick = borrar;
</script>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Marcos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El primer problema es que al colocar un botón dentro de un formulario, este por defecto enviará dicho formulario al hacer click como si se le agregara un:

```
type="submit"
```

para evitar ese comportamiento puedes agergarle un:

```
type="button"
```

de esa manera el formulario no se enviará al hacer click al boton.

Segundo, si quieres que el botón borrar deje los campos del formulario en blanco no necesitas crear una función, basta con agregar:

```
type="reset"
```

y el código te queda así:

```html
<body>
<form action="" name="formulario" id="formulario">
    <input type="text" id="texto1" name="texto1" value="" placeholder="nombre">
    <input type="text" id="texto2"  value="" placeholder="apellido">
    <input type="text" id="texto3"  value="" placeholder="edad">
    <button type="button" id="boton1">Enviar</button>
    <button type="reset" id="boton2">Eliminar</button>
</form>
<script>
    function datos(){
        var uno = document.getElementById("texto1").value;
        var dos = document.getElementById("texto2").value;
        var tres = document.getElementById("texto3").value;
        var arreglo = [uno, dos, tres];
        return arreglo;
    }

    function alerta(){
        var arreglo = datos();
        alert(`Su nombre es ${arreglo[0]}, su apellido ${arreglo[1]} y su edad ${arreglo[2]}`);
    }
    boton1.onclick = alerta;
    
</script>
</body>
```

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: El problema es que no sabía que por defecto era submit por lo que ambas respuestas me han sido de gran ayuda.
 MUchas gracias

Comment: @Marcos claro, enseguida.